# Ubuntu black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: networking, programming

My Ubuntu is not working, the version is 22.04 it is showing me black screen with blinking cursor and when i am trying all the possible commands it is showing me no space left on disk . Now i don't know how to make this work so please give me a solution

Comment: Either enlarge your partition with a live USB Stick (it contains `gparted`) or remove data from your /home/ directory. The problem is clear: You don't have enough space to run a graphical environment

Comment: What is the size of the partition you allocated to Ubuntu? No disk space no boot. List the commands you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)